# Url is undefined in JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am developing an application in which I am retrieving data from the database into GirdView. Now when any user clicks on the Get City, it should return the city name of that particular row.

[image]

But i am getting the following error:

[image]

Following is my script code:

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("a").one("click", function (evt) {
            debugger;
            var stu_id = $(evt.target).closest("tr").children(":first-child").text();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'WebForm1.aspx/get_city',
                data: "{'stuid':'" + stu_id +"'}",
                async: false,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (final) {
                    debugger;
                    $("#LblCity").append(final.d + "<hr/>");
                },
                error: function () {
                    debugger;
                    alert('error');
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

My WebForm1.aspx.cs page code:

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string Get_City(int stuid)
    {
        MyDatabaseEntities MyDb = new MyDatabaseEntities();

        var data = from db in MyDb.Students
                   where db.ID == stuid
                   select db.City;
        return data.SingleOrDefault().ToString();
    }
```

Comment: What is the error? Your tooltip is showing the jQuery source for `$.ajax`, not an error message. Have you checked the console?

Comment: I am sorry for that, the error is URL is undefined. @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan nothing is happening when i am clicking on the Get City. please help.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yup. There is no error message on the Console.

Comment: Have you put breakpoint inside webmethod  to see if the code goes there?

Comment: Yup I inserted the breakpoint inside the WebMethod, but the bebugger is not going there. @kostasch.

Comment: Is the breakpoint red? I mean it might be "The break point will not currently be hit.No Symbols have been loaded for this document."

Comment: You can also use pagemethods and script manager.

Comment: @kostasch I inserted the debugger in the Script also but in the developer mode, the debugger is not debugging after the $.ajax({

Comment: About the breakpoiint i mean to the webmethod.

Comment: @kostasch.would you please edit the code with the use of pagemethod or script manager.

Comment: Yes @kostasch I put the breakpoint inside in the WebMethod.

Comment: And does not appear  "The break point will not currently be hit.No Symbols have been loaded for this document."?

Comment: I am not getting your point. @kostasch.

Comment: Sometimes when you set break point, debugger not stop and the break point has the above message and is not red, it is red around and is empty inside.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51727/discussion-between-nimit-joshi-and-kostas-ch)

Comment: @NimitJoshi Sorry for the offtopic, but what IDE are you using?

Comment: Visual Studio 2013, .NET framework (latest) @Deepsy

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. I am using Visual Studio 2013 so I just update the `RouteConfig.cs` file with the following code:

```
settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off;
```

Now everything is running fine. Thanks for helping me.